# Authorize.Net Transaction Details API Not Returning LineItems

Tags: c#, asp.net, e-commerce, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I'm using the `Transaction Details API` with the `Authorize.Net C# SDK` to get a list of all transactions in the past 30 days using the following code directly from the [Authorize.Net website](http://developer.authorize.net/api/transaction_details/):

```
        //open a call to the Gateway
        var gate = new ReportingGateway("myAPILogin", "myTransactionKey");

        //Get all the batches settled
        var batches = gate.GetSettledBatchList();

        Console.WriteLine("All Batches in the last 30 days");

        //Loop each batch returned
        foreach (var item in batches)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Batch ID: {0}, Settled On : {1}", item.ID,
                              item.SettledOn.ToShortDateString());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("*****************************************************");
        Console.WriteLine();

        //get all Transactions for the last 30 days
        var transactions = gate.GetTransactionList();
        foreach (var item in transactions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Transaction {0}: Card: {1} for {2} on {3}",
                              item.TransactionID, item.CardNumber,
                              item.SettleAmount.ToString("C"),
                              item.DateSubmitted.ToShortDateString());
        }
```

and it works properly. I am trying to get the list of `LineItems` for each `Transaction` by adding this:

```
        ...
        foreach (var item in transactions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Transaction {0}: Card: {1} for {2} on {3}",
                              item.TransactionID, item.CardNumber,
                              item.SettleAmount.ToString("C"),
                              item.DateSubmitted.ToShortDateString());
            foreach (var li in item.LineItems)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("    LineItem ID: {0} Name: {1} Quantity: {2} Unit Price: {3}",
                              li.ID, li.Name, li.Quantity, li.UnitPrice);
            }
        }
```

It doesn't show any `LineItems` though, I even set a break point and saw that it always shows 0 `LineItems` for each transaction, even though I can log into the web interface and view the `LineItems` in the transaction detail reports.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? How do I view `LineItems` of each transaction using the `Authorize.Net C# SDK`?

**ANSWER:** (thanks to SO User [Josh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10852600/585552))

```
        ...
        var transactions = gate.GetTransactionList();
        foreach (var item in transactions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Transaction {0}: Card: {1} for {2} on {3}",
                              item.TransactionID, item.CardNumber,
                              item.SettleAmount.ToString("C"),
                              item.DateSubmitted.ToShortDateString());

            var details = gate.GetTransactionDetails(item.TransactionID);

            foreach (var li in details.LineItems)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("    LineItem ID: {0} Name: {1} Quantity: {2} Unit Price: {3}",
                              li.ID, li.Name, li.Quantity, li.UnitPrice);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GetTransactionList returns limited information about the transaction.  On each transaction, do a GetTransactionDetails:

**GetTransactionList** This function returns limited transaction details for a specified batch ID.

**GetTransactionDetails** This function returns full transaction details for a specified transaction ID.

Found from Authorize.net's XML API library [Look towards the bottom on the XML section](https://developer.authorize.net/api/transaction_details/)